# Assert when module version is too modern

Tags: perl

How to assert if the script is using too-modern version of modules?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Encode;
use version;

# no v5.00;         # Works as I expected
# no Encode v2.80;  # But this doesn't work

# What I want to do is:
BEGIN {
    my $current = version->parse($Encode::VERSION);
    my $fatal = version->parse('v2.80');
    if ($current >= $fatal) {
        die "Encode.pm since $fatal too modern--this is $current";
    }
}
```

It seems like I can use function `no`, to restrict module version.  But no luck.

https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/no.html

> no MODULE VERSION

Comment: As an aside, these sort of checks are a fool's errand. It is similar to the problem with declaring "conflicts" in the prerequisites of a CPAN module. CPAN clients are not package managers, and so there is nothing keeping the newer version from getting installed when something else needs it. If you need version pinning or restriction, you have to use something like [Carton](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carton) or use a package manager like RPM.

Comment: Also small nitpick: you should use `Encode->VERSION` to get the version rather than reading `$Encode::VERSION` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`no` performs the same check as `use`.

For example, if you wanted to disable autovivification, and you needed one of the fixes in version 0.18 of the module, you'd use

```
no autovivification 0.18;
```

As such, you must indeed add your own check as you showed.

---

Specifically,

```
use Module v2.80;
```

is equivalent to

```
BEGIN {
   require Module;
   Module->VERSION(v2.80);  # Make sure >= v2.80
   Module->import();
}
```

while

```
no Module v2.80;
```

is equivalent to

```
BEGIN {
   require Module;
   Module->VERSION(v2.80);  # Make sure >= v2.80
   Module->unimport();
}
```

Comment: The last example just made sense to me. Thanks